# Use google mock's EXPECT_THAT in EXPECT_CALL?

Tags: c++, mocking, googlemock

I'm using google mock. The document says that we can use EXPECT_THAT in EXPECT_CALL or ON_CALL, but code like this doesn't seem to compile:

```
EXPECT_CALL(obj, method(_, _)).Times(1).WillOnce(EXPECT_THAT(true, Eq(1)));
```

I know EXPECT_THAT is a macro so it expands to some statements that shouldn't appear there. So what does "use EXPECT_THAT in EXPECT_CALL" mean? How to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've misunderstood the [documentation for matchers](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#matchers):

> A matcher matches a single argument. You can use it inside ON_CALL() or EXPECT_CALL(), or use it to validate a value directly

The docs then go on to give an example of *how* you could use a matcher to validate a value:

> `EXPECT_THAT(value, matcher)`Asserts that `value` matches `matcher`.

This is not saying that `EXPECT_THAT` is itself a matcher.  So you can't do what you're attempting, but only something more like:

```
EXPECT_THAT(true, testing::Eq(1));
```

or

```
EXPECT_CALL(obj, method(testing::_, testing::Eq(1))).Times(1);
```